# How to precompile assets before running a Rails App on a ECS Fargate environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker

I have a CodePipeline set-up that tracks updates to a private GIT repo. When a change is detected, a CodeBuild task is run to turn the repo into a Docker Image and pushes it to ECR. After that I run a CodeDeploy task to update the ECS cluster by running `rake db:migrate` and restarting the tasks.

All fine so far. But when I try to access my Rails app, I'm seeing the following error:

`ActionView::Template::Error` *occurred while* `GET </>` *was processed by* `statics#home`
Exception
The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.

It seems that I need to run `rake assets:precompile` somewhere. I don't know how to make that work, should I:

1. Define the precompilation in my Dockerfile?
2. run the command in my CodeBuild script?
3. Do something else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Dockerfile -
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile